# ignore parent/ancestor environments inside function (disable lexical scoping)

Tags: r, scope, environment

Is there a way to disable lexical scoping in R? I want to prevent a function from using any of its parent/ancestor environments. The desired behavior is an error below (`x` not found).

```
x <- 1
f <- function() 
  eval(parse(text = "x"), 
       envir = new.env(), 
       enclos = new.env())
f() # returns 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the environment of your function to be the `baseenv()` which will not search the global environment

```
x <- 1
f <- function() return(x);
environment(f) <- baseenv()
f() 
# Error in f() : object 'x' not found
```

This doesn't "disable" lexical scoping so much as it changes the search to skip the global environment.

You can use `baseenv()` with the `eval(envir=)` or `new.env(parent=)` parameters if you need to.

```
x <- 1
f <- function() 
  eval(parse(text = "x"), 
       envir = baseenv())
f()
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```